# CI Cart session is dropped because of '\' character

Tags: codeigniter, session, cart

I have a CodeIgniter cart that stores a URL in the options array. The problem is that when a URL with a '/' ( eg. www.website.com/page ) is added, the cart is emptied when the user leaves the cart contents page. This behavior is browser-independant.

This is what it looks like in the ci_session table after the item is added to the cart.

```
s:56:"{"aid":"111111","url":"www.testing.again.com\/whatisup"}"
```

Notice that the '\' escape character has been added to the URL.

So how can I fix this? My first thought is to do a str_replace to change the '/' to something else like '|' and then put the '/' back in later. I suspect there is a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the URL in the cart for? Normally you just put the object ID in the cart, and then fetch properties of each item as needed.

Comment: The URL is a product option, like a color or size would be for a shirt. So I grab some info from the user like the 'aid', the URL and sometimes a phone number and name. This all goes into the CI cart options array.

Comment: So I tried the str_escape idea and it works, but is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can `base64_encode`, `base64_decode` to encode/decode the URL. However, if you aren't using db_session, this will take up more room in the cookie pushing you towards the 5kb limit on cookie storage--so keep that in mind.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php